# Electric flux over a closed surface when point charge lies on the surface

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, mathematical-physics

What will be the electric flux over a closed surface when point charge lies on the surface, that is neither inside nor outside? I ask this question because electric field at that point will be indeterminate. So how can we find flux over that surface if electric field at a point on the surface is indeterminate?

Comment: Are you saying that this surface perfectly bisects the point charge? Like an orange cut in half?

Comment: I mean if in Cartesian coordinates (1,2,3) is a point on the closed surface, then (1,2 3) is also the coordinates of point charge. BTW how can we cut a dimensionless point in half?

Comment: Point charges are a mathematical construction. I was trying to understand what is was that you were asking.

Comment: My guess would be that it is $\frac{1}{2}q/\varepsilon_0$.

Comment: Why? Is it because it is neither inside nor outside and hence it is considered half inside and half outside?

Comment: I can't see this case in any books or online articles

Comment: It's just a guess. I'd have to think about it a little more.

Comment: Here is a link to a post on a similar (if not the same) question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57705/why-doesnt-a-gaussian-surface-pass-through-discrete-charges. Apparently this is addressed in Purcell's book.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83578/discussion-between-faheemahmed400-and-alex-opremcak).